# Using Images from Database with URL

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, simplecursoradapter, universal-image-loader

I am caching all data I'm getting in my App inside a SQLite DB... Whenever the user doesn't have internet connection the data is loaded with a SimpleCursorAdapter from the database.
The database also contains the URL of Images. The images are cached by the image loading framework I'm using (Universal-Image-Loader), so when I run the framework with the URL from the database it gets the cached image.
My question is how I can call this method inside my SimpleCursorAdapter?
Until now I have only been able to get all the texts from the database and attach them to TextViews...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was finally able to get this done myself...

I had to write a new method which extends CursorAdapter...

There I had to assign all my Texts I got from my DB with the TextView. So I was also able to give my Image Loader the Link to the (cached) image to load...

This is my code:

```
private static final class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);

        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_twitter, parent, false);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView listtitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listtitle);
        TextView listusername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listusername);
        TextView listdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listdate);

        listtitle.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.KEY_TWITTER_TWEET)));
        listusername.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.KEY_TWITTER_USERNAME)));
        listdate.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.KEY_TWITTER_DATE)));

        listtitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        listdate.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageLoader.displayImage(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataDBAdapter.KEY_TWITTER_IMAGEURL)),
                iv, options);
    }

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
}
```

And this actually works pretty well :)